# Why do certain tags go a new line when using HtmlTextWriter?

Tags: c#, formatting, htmltextwriter, word-wrap

I'm having a bit of a hard time trying to format my HTML when using HtmlTextWriter. It seems that some tags will automatically go to a new line and some won't.

Is there a way to stop this from happening so all tags are created equally and leave the formatting completely up to me?

In my particular case I'm building out a `<ul>`'s and `<li>`'s for a custom HTML Sitemap.

The immediate tag that comes after an `<ul>` will wrap to a new line.
This is not the case for a `<li>` tag.

If anyone needs clarification please ask question.

Comment: Yes, we need clarification. Why don't you clearly show some code, and clearly show what output you receive and what results you expected.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using `RenderBeginTag`? That method will handle some things automatically, and among other things, it will put line breaks (and indentation) in elements that aren't inline (e.g. `ul` versus `span`).

If you want to do the rendering manually, use `WriteBeginTag("ul")` or `WriteFullBeginTag("ul")` instead.

Note that `WriteBeginTag` will still handle indentation. However, you have full control over that if you only use the `WriteXXX` methods.

In the end, though, do those endlines really bother you at all? You do use compression, right? The overhead usually isn't very significant...

Comment: I'm just a stickler when it comes to HTML formatting. When a person views the source of a page I like it to be as readable as possible.

Comment: @g5insider And *removing* whitespace helps with that? =) In any case, if that's what you want, just use the `WriteXXX` methods, and you can do the formatting any way you want. You can't really change the behaviour of `RenderXXX` - the tag types are stored in static private fields, and overriding the writer won't help you if you can't also create it yourself.

Comment: I like well formatted HTML. I tried my best at formatting it and it looks way better than it did before. I appreciate all the help. Thanks!

Comment: when i tried rendering the html output on the body of outlook email template it is not rendering correctly,can anyone help   all the html tag,head tag,div tag are endering as follows                                                                         <43><41></41><12><25>Hello World</25></12></43>